# GIT - working with multiple machines

Tags: git, git-branch

We currently have a web hosted git project ( the origin ) with two standard branches: develop & master. We've been using the standard local-feature branch workflow and push the to remote develop branch only when the feature is ready.

Recently I've started working from home as well, so i would like to share my work between the two machines. However, I do not want to push 'work in progress' to the remote develop branch. 
Also, the work machine is not accessible outside of the office.

I'm thinking about making a develop-user branch, which will be my working branch ( on the remote as well) and hold all the 'work in progress' commits that I can push for both machines and later merge into the develop or feature branch.

To me this looks like a good solution for the situation. Are there any better / more practical workflows for this situation?

Comment: If you really need to keep the in development code off of the remote machine you could as a day to day practice you could generate patches and mail/copy via media them to your home machine.

Comment: I would like to keep the process as simple as possible and not to include another set of action( generate, copy, paste, merge).

Comment: Move your project directory to a portable hard-drive, (if the rules at your work allow this).

Answer (score 0):

If you already work on a feature branch, why not push that instead of a personal one?

You can have some branch-naming convention in your team to tell which branches are *personal* and which ones are *stable*/public and other teammates can collaborate on. No one but "it's owner" should work on a personal branch, as it could contain WIP commits that are likely to be rebased in the future. And that's all the *care* you have to have.

Comment: It might not be the best solution, but the idea is to keep the remote repo as clutter as possible and pushing every feature branch generates a lot of clutter.

Comment: @sustbn You can always _delete_ the remote branch after it's merged back into `develop` with `git push origin :remote-feature-branch`.